Were flight crew allowed to carry firearms before 9/11?
After the devastating terrorist attacks on September 11, 2001, many aspects of aviation safety and security were improved and/or enforced.
These security measures and enhancements include:

More complete and effective security checks in the airport
Reinforced cockpit doors
Strict regulations that forbid any non-flight crew member to enter the cockpit in flight
Probititation on flight crew opening the cockpit door due to demands or threats by terrorists

Another reaction to the terrorist attacks was the Federal Flight Deck Officer (FFDO) program, which allows federally approved, fully trained and licensed pilots to carry firearms in the cockpit.
However, in the Wikipedia article  states that:

Pilots are now allowed to carry firearms, but they must be trained and licensed.

Where  the use of the word "now" doesn't explicitly state that it was originally forbidden.
Likewise, the article on FFDO states that

Following the September 11 attacks in 2001, the Arming Pilots Against Terrorism Act, part of the Homeland Security Act of 2002, directed the Transportation Security Administration to develop the Federal Flight Deck Officer program as an additional layer of security.

Which only conveys the message that the FFDO program was initiated after 9/11, and also doesn't directly state that carrying firearms was illegal before 9/11.
Before 9/11, was it illegal for a pilot, who is also a fully trained and qualified legal firearm user to carry it in the cockpit?

@Jamiec In this post, I found the two Wikipedia pages that I find most relevant, so I included them here and also explains why they didn't solve my problem. And indeed no one complain about lack of research now, but this time it's of too much detail, so I'm wondering, what amount/type of research should I include? I would appreciate any advice, as I'm really puzzled now. (Note: I got around 60 downvotes (worth ~120 points) due to that lack of research thing, so you can see why I'm irritated and overcompensating here).

I would suggest you read some highly upvoted questions on topics that interest you to get a feel for how much detail to provide in your question.

I've reworked this question. Important points: 1) Some structure, using bullets, quotes, etc. 2) I didnt actually remove many words, just the fluff around them. 3) What I did remove was commentary, and hopefully keeps your question intact

When KLM began flying to Tokyo from Amsterdam in 1958, the route took them via Anchorage and then over the top of the world. The plane was a DC-7C, PH-DSC "Yellow Sea", and would be carrying 100 passengers.
KLM took into consideration the hazards that would face them following a forced landing, which included polar bear attack, and so purchased five or six ArmaLite AR-10 rifles for use on the Polar Route flights.

KLM gave transpolar flight crews survival training and presumably some
guidance on weapons handling but no actual trigger time with the
rifles instead advising them to simply aim between an attacking polar
bear’s shoulder blades.
source

Further details of the survival kit, including unique four-person sleeping-bags, maps, tissues, tents, a raft, a shovel, snow shoes, a small camp stove, candles, cold weather clothes, a hatchet and a saw can be found here.

The crew of the "Yellow Sea" prior to flying over the arctic from Anchorage to Tokyo, November 1958.

KLM stewardess (Puck Rijpstra?) with an AR-10 rifle during training before the polar flights.
